# iPhone SDK: Text between UITableView sections?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, user-interface

In the settings on the iphone, there is text between some of the UITableView sections.  Sometimes larger text, sometimes smaller text.  How do I do this?

[Safari http://www.zedsaid.com/__data/assets/image/0019/1765/safari.png](http://www.zedsaid.com/__data/assets/image/0019/1765/safari.png)

I would like to know how to do the "Security" text, as well as the "Warn when visiting fraudulent websites." text.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are section headers and footers. You can set them in table view datasource `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` and `tableView:titleForFooterInSection:` methods